# Angular JS UI-Router Example not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to JS, and am trying out a simple Angular ui-router example, but I can't seem to get the router working, and can't see why. I've tested a few examples to make sure angular has been loaded and custom.js has been loaded (which they are), but when I come to using the router I get nothing, from my little knowledge I can't see anything glaringly obvious (this is basically and copy and paste example).

--HTML---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "routerApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angularmin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
TEST APP
<div ui-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

--js/custom.js--

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home-partial.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

Comment: Please check  the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not referenced the js file for ui-router,

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angularmin.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js" > </script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/W66a4hUvxF4z9717i0GV?p=preview)

Comment: does that need to be downloaded separately?

Comment: @SamPalmer yes indeed

Comment: ah I thought it was part of the original angular code, so I just used bower to download it, and include "angular-ui-router.js", but still no result

Comment: @SamPalmer did you check the sample app?

Comment: so I need to build the angular-ui-router after using bower? As I can't see angular-ui-router.js anywhere

Comment: bower install angular-ui-router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122692/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sam-palmer).